# Create pandas dataframe based on row search substring value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am struggling to shape my Python data into a dataframe.  Can anyone help me with the code that might get me there?  It seems the easiest solution would be to create columns based on substrings of text from the rows but I cannot find documentation to get me the shape I am seeking from the rows.

[Original Dataframe - no column headers, data all in rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGBWC.png)

[Desired Dataframe - bounding box rows to columns with uniform header, confidence to column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3uvU.png)

My response is structured as follows:
{
"status": "succeeded",
"createdDateTime": "2020-08-28T19:21:29Z",
"lastUpdatedDateTime": "2020-08-28T19:21:31Z",
"analyzeResult": {
"version": "3.0.0",
"readResults": [{
"page": 1,
"angle": 0.1296,
"width": 1700,
"height": 2200,
"unit": "pixel",
"lines": [{
"boundingBox": [
182,
119,
383,
119,
383,
161,
182,
160
],
"text": "FORM 101",
"words": [{
"boundingBox": [
183,
120,
305,
120,
305,
161,
182,
161
],
"text": "FORM",
"confidence": 0.987
},
{
"boundingBox": [
318,
120,
381,
120,
382,
162,
318,
161
],
"text": "101",
"confidence": 0.987
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
578,
129,
1121,
129,
1121,
163,
578,
162
],
"text": "The Commonwealth of Massachusetts",
"words": [{
"boundingBox": [
579,
129,
634,
129,
634,
162,
579,
161
],
"text": "The",
"confidence": 0.988
},
{
"boundingBox": [
641,
129,
868,
129,
866,
164,
640,
162
],
"text": "Commonwealth",
"confidence": 0.979
},
{
"boundingBox": [
874,
129,
902,
129,
900,
164,
872,
164
],
"text": "of",
"confidence": 0.988
},
{
"boundingBox": [
908,
129,
1120,
130,
1117,
163,
906,
164
],
"text": "Massachusetts",
"confidence": 0.977
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1341,
137,
1540,
138,
1540,
164,
1341,
163
],
"text": "DIA USE ONLY",
"words": [{
"boundingBox": [
1342,
138,
1392,
138,
1392,
164,
1341,
163
],
"text": "DIA",
"confidence": 0.983
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1397,
138,
1452,
139,
1452,
164,
1397,
164
],
"text": "USE",
"confidence": 0.983
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1457,
139,
1539,
138,
1540,
164,
1457,
164
],
"text": "ONLY",
"confidence": 0.986
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
459,
169,
1235,
168,
1235,
202,
459,
203
],
"text": "Department of Industrial Accidents - Department 101",
"words": [{
"boundingBox": [
460,
170,
634,
170,
634,
203,
460,
204
],
"text": "Department",
"confidence": 0.981
},
{
"boundingBox": [
640,
170,
669,
170,
669,
203,
640,
203
],
"text": "of",
"confidence": 0.983
},
{
"boundingBox": [
676,
170,
821,
169,
821,
203,
676,
203
],
"text": "Industrial",
"confidence": 0.981
},
{
"boundingBox": [
828,
169,
967,
169,
966,
203,
828,
203
],
"text": "Accidents",
"confidence": 0.952
},
{
"boundingBox": [
973,
169,
993,
169,
993,
203,
973,
203
],
"text": "-",
"confidence": 0.983
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1000,
169,
1176,
169,
1176,
203,
999,
203
],
"text": "Department",
"confidence": 0.982
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1183,
169,
1236,
169,
1235,
203,
1182,
203
],
"text": "101",
"confidence": 0.987
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
511,
205,
1189,
205,
1189,
233,
511,
234
],
"text": "1 Congress Street, Suite 100, Boston, Massachusetts 02114-2017",
"words": [{
"boundingBox": [
513,
206,
520,
206,
519,
233,
512,
233
],
"text": "1",
"confidence": 0.974
},
{
"boundingBox": [
525,
206,
625,
206,
624,
234,
524,
233
],
"text": "Congress",
"confidence": 0.981
},
{
"boundingBox": [
630,
206,
702,
206,
701,
234,
629,
234
],
"text": "Street,",
"confidence": 0.977
},
{
"boundingBox": [
707,
206,
763,
206,
762,
234,
706,
234
],
"text": "Suite",
"confidence": 0.983
},
{
"boundingBox": [
769,
206,
812,
206,
811,
234,
767,
234
],
"text": "100,",
"confidence": 0.983
},
{
"boundingBox": [
818,
206,
898,
206,
897,
234,
816,
234
],
"text": "Boston,",
"confidence": 0.983
},
{
"boundingBox": [
903,
206,
1059,
205,
1058,
234,
902,
234
],
"text": "Massachusetts",
"confidence": 0.975
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1064,
205,
1189,
205,
1187,
233,
1063,
234
],
"text": "02114-2017",
"confidence": 0.978
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
422,
236,
1279,
237,
1279,
263,
422,
263
],
"text": "Info. Line 800-323-3249 ext. 470 in Mass. Outside Mass. - 617-727-4900 ext. 470",
"words": [{
"boundingBox": [
423,
237,
472,
237,
472,
263,
422,
263
],
"text": "Info.",
"confidence": 0.983
},
{
"boundingBox": [
477,
237,
526,
237,
526,
264,
477,
264
],
"text": "Line",
"confidence": 0.986
},
{
"boundingBox": [
531,
237,
674,
237,
674,
264,
531,
264
],
"text": "800-323-3249",
"confidence": 0.977
},
{
"boundingBox": [
679,
237,
718,
237,
718,
264,
679,
264
],
"text": "ext.",
"confidence": 0.982
},
{
"boundingBox": [
724,
237,
763,
237,
763,
264,
723,
264
],
"text": "470",
"confidence": 0.986
},
{
"boundingBox": [
768,
237,
790,
237,
790,
264,
768,
264
],
"text": "in",
"confidence": 0.987
},
{
"boundingBox": [
795,
237,
865,
237,
865,
264,
795,
264
],
"text": "Mass.",
"confidence": 0.983
},
{
"boundingBox": [
870,
237,
953,
237,
953,
264,
870,
264
],
"text": "Outside",
"confidence": 0.981
},
{
"boundingBox": [
958,
237,
1019,
237,
1020,
264,
958,
264
],
"text": "Mass.",
"confidence": 0.984
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1025,
237,
1036,
237,
1037,
264,
1025,
264
],
"text": "-",
"confidence": 0.983
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1042,
237,
1184,
237,
1185,
264,
1042,
264
],
"text": "617-727-4900",
"confidence": 0.975
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1190,
237,
1229,
238,
1229,
264,
1190,
264
],
"text": "ext.",
"confidence": 0.985
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1234,
238,
1278,
238,
1278,
264,
1234,
264
],
"text": "470",
"confidence": 0.983
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
716,
264,
984,
266,
984,
293,
715,
292
],
"text": "http://www.mass.gov/dia",
"words": [{
"boundingBox": [
717,
265,
985,
267,
984,
294,
716,
293
],
"text": "http://www.mass.gov/dia",
"confidence": 0.952
}]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
398,
299,
1289,
299,
1289,
342,
398,
342
],
"text": "EMPLOYER'S FIRST REPORT OF INJURY",
"words": [{
"boundingBox": [
399,
300,
693,
300,
693,
341,
399,
343
],
"text": "EMPLOYER'S",
"confidence": 0.98
},
{
"boundingBox": [
702,
300,
836,
300,
836,
341,
702,
341
],
"text": "FIRST",
"confidence": 0.982
},
{
"boundingBox": [
845,
300,
1036,
300,
1036,
341,
844,
341
],
"text": "REPORT",
"confidence": 0.985
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1045,
300,
1105,
300,
1104,
342,
1044,
341
],
"text": "OF",
"confidence": 0.988
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1113,
300,
1288,
299,
1287,
343,
1113,
342
],
"text": "INJURY",
"confidence": 0.986
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
691,
354,
1005,
355,
1005,
395,
691,
393
],
"text": "OR FATALITY",
"words": [{
"boundingBox": [
691,
354,
760,
355,
760,
395,
692,
394
],
"text": "OR",
"confidence": 0.988
},
{
"boundingBox": [
768,
355,
1005,
356,
1003,
395,
768,
395
],
"text": "FATALITY",
"confidence": 0.981
}
]
}
]
}]
}
}

Comment: provide original data frame as text. `print(df.to_dict(orient="records"))` so we don't have to go through OCR

Answer (score 0):

Without supplying your data or an explanation this mostly does what you want.

1. comments explain approach
2. there is more work to be done on *linekey* however I cannot see the relationship between the actual data and the outcome you posted as an image

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
{0:["analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_text","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_0_boundingBox_0","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_0_boundingBox_1","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_0_boundingBox_2","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_0_boundingBox_3","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_0_boundingBox_4","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_0_boundingBox_5","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_0_boundingBox_6","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_0_boundingBox_7","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_0_text","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_0_confidence","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_1_boundingBox_0","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_1_boundingBox_1","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_1_boundingBox_2","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_1_boundingBox_3","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_1_boundingBox_4","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_1_boundingBox_5","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_1_boundingBox_6","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_1_boundingBox_7","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_1_text","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_1_confidence","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_1_boundingBox_0","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_1_boundingBox_1","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_1_boundingBox_2","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_1_boundingBox_3","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_1_boundingBox_4","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_1_boundingBox_5","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_1_boundingBox_6","analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_1_boundingBox_7"],

 1:["FORM 101",183,120,305,120,305,161,182,161,"FORM",0.987,318,120,381,120,382,162,318,161,101,0.987,578,129,1121,129,1121,163,578,162],
},
 index=[17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45]
)

df = (
df
    .rename(columns={0:"key",1:"val"})
    .assign(
        b=lambda x: x["key"].str.extract("(.*)_bounding"),
        c=lambda x: x["key"].str.extract("(.*)_confidence"),
        # linekey is everything before "_bounding" or "_confidence". pull the two together
        linekey=lambda x: np.where(x["b"].isna(), 
                             np.where(x["c"].isna(), x["key"], x["c"]), 
                             x["b"]),
        # column key is every thing after line key minus leading "_"
        colkey=lambda x: x.apply(lambda r: r["key"].replace(r["linekey"], "").strip("_"), axis=1)
    )
    .assign(
        # cleanup special case line keys...
        colkey=lambda x: np.where(x["colkey"]=="", "Value", x["colkey"].replace("confidence","Confidence"))
    )
    # remove working columns
    .drop(columns=["b","c","key"])
    # mixed values and strings so use "first" and unstack to get to desired layout
    .groupby(["linekey","colkey"]).agg({"val":"first"}).unstack()
)

print(df.to_string())
```

**output**

```
                                                        val                                                                                                                          
colkey                                           Confidence     Value boundingBox_0 boundingBox_1 boundingBox_2 boundingBox_3 boundingBox_4 boundingBox_5 boundingBox_6 boundingBox_7
linekey                                                                                                                                                                              
analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_text                NaN  FORM 101           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_0           0.987       NaN           183           120           305           120           305           161           182           161
analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_0_text        NaN      FORM           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_1           0.987       NaN           318           120           381           120           382           162           318           161
analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_0_words_1_text        NaN       101           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
analyzeResult_readResults_0_lines_1                     NaN       NaN           578           129          1121           129          1121           163           578           162
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rob.  Is there any way to refrain from naming the items in the rows and columns and instead to use a substring to move the items there?  In other words, there are a variable number of bounding boxes depending on how many words are in a key phrase but if the word "bound box" appears then I want to move it to columns.  Also it could error out because of the variation in words.  Some phrases have 2 words, some have 20.

Comment: that's exactly how it works... it's looking for "bounding" without any limits.  `b=lambda x: x["key"].str.extract("(.*)_bounding"),` no limit on number...

Comment: Hi, I ran it against my code and it is only picking up the rows and columns where you specified the values near the top of the code block.  It does not appear to be iterating through the entire response and formatting it all the same way.

Comment: odd - can you share the data with me?  google drive/github or something? happy to look

Comment: Yes I can Rob.  Thank you for spending the time.

Comment: Hi, any ideas why it is only giving me values for the sample I provided here?  It is not iterating through my entire JSON.

Comment: Also, the text value is not aligned on the same row as the confidence and bounding boxes.  Any chance you know the code to get the values in the same row, to minimize the nulls?

Comment: the solution I provided does this through the `groupby()` after working out *linekey* and *colkey*.  so fact that source data is across multiple lines is catered for,  but it's all in extracting a target line in the *linekey*